# Reversing order of outcome variable - multinomial logistic regression

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, multinomial-logit

Here is a working example of my issue:

I am trying to predict an outcome variable with three levels (e.g. underweight, normal weight, overweight) from a series of categorical variables (e.g. eats fast food (yes/no)). I am using multinomial logistic regression. I am interested in deviations from normal weight, so set this as the base category.

The predictors are significant, with eating fast food decreasing the odds of being in the underweight category (vs normal weight; OR = 0.30) and increasing the odds of being in the overweight category (vs normal weight; OR = 5.40). The latter is easy to interpret: eating fast food increases the odds of being overweight (OR = 5.40). I would like to reverse the former though to make it easier to interpret, so the odds reflect going from underweight to normal weight. Can I do this by inversing the OR and confidence intervals, so eating fast food increases the odds of being normal weight vs underweight by 3.33 (1/0.30)? Is this the correct way of doing it?